How to increase the counter of the subsections in eledpar?
How to increase the counter of the subsections which produces lower numbers than the counter of the sections?
Thanks for any help!
    %LuaLaTex
\documentclass[a4paper,12p,headinclude]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar,lipsum,eledmac,hyperref}
\usepackage{verse,marginnote}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\babelprovide[import]{ancientgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\pretolerance -1
\hbadness=10000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

\begin{document}
\title{Johannes von Damaskus\\
Drei Reden \textit{Über XY}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\newcommand{\myhead}{Drei Reden zur Entschlafung der Gottesgebärerin}
\chead{\myhead}
\cohead{\myhead}
\rofoot{\rightmark}
\lefoot{\leftmark}


\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΠΡΩΤΟΣ ΕΙΣ ΤΗΝ ΚΟΙΜΗΣΙΝ}
   \pend

\pstart
 \selectlanguage{greek}
\textbf{ Ἰωάννου Überschrift.}\\


\subsection{First headline left side}% Should be on the left page: 1.1
α'. Μνήμη, ἀληθινήν; Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος  \\

\subsection{Second headline left side}%1.2
βʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ERSTE PREDIGT}
 \pend
\pstart

\subsection{First headline right side}%Should be on the right page: 1.1 ...
Es sagte der 

\subsection{Second headline right side}% 1.2
Duis autem vel  
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 

\Pages
\end{document}



Can you a) boil down your example to a small test document and b) clarify which subsection should have which number?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, done. Thank you.

@Onur, thank you. But unfortunately it doesn't work in my texmaker. Please, tell me what you suggested.

We keep editing your post so that your code looks like code, and you keep undoing that.  Please let us help you.  You also have not done either of samcarter's requests.  Please change each paragraph to be three words long, and tell us what numbering you would like in the output.

@Teepeemm, thank you so much.  Hope now it's better. I'm new here.

Please read marked as a code sample

Not sure, but isn't the eledmac package somewhat outdated?

@RaphaelBlasberg it was just a cosmetic update from my side (implemented code snippet view to have a better understanding on overall code) - nothing to worry about, can be discarded.

The incorrect subsections numbering appears because you're using \eledsection and \subsection. Use either \section and \subsection, or \eledsection and \eledsubsection. By the way, the eledmac package (that you load twice) is depreciated. Use reledmac instead. Replace also eledpar by reledpar.
